# Get a contact phone number crash

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a user choose a contact and retrieve his phone number. I found the following code [here](https://developer.android.com).

```
//the onClick function for the user to pick his contact

public void pickContact(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }
}

//the function that should retrieve the phone number

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the URI and query the content provider for the phone number
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
        // If the cursor returned is valid, get the phone number
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
            // Do something with the phone number
        }         
    }
}
```

I don't know why but when the user chooses a contact, the app crashes with the following error: E/EGL_emulation: tid 5883: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): `error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)`. From debugging, it seems that it crashes in this line:

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(contactUri,
                projection, null, null, null);
```

logcat messages:

```
03-07 11:16:53.239 5866-5883/com.example.roy.wakeapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-07 11:16:53.265 5866-5883/com.example.roy.wakeapp E/EGL_emulation: tid 5883: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-07 11:16:53.265 5866-5883/com.example.roy.wakeapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad1ab480, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

I tried to look it up, but I couldn't find the reason. If someone knows the reason or can provide a different way of doing that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What crash are u getting??

Comment: You'll have to paste the full stacktrace here.

Comment: @Yashasvi how to i get the  full stacktrace?

Comment: I get E/EGL_emulation: tid 5883: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH).

Comment: as soon as the crash happens, you'll see the stack trace in android studio logcat

Comment: i editted the question with the stack trace of the crash. thnks

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating `Intent` as follows

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICK);
```

and activity result method

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CONTACT_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the URI and query the content provider for the phone number
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
            Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection,
                    null, null, null);

            // If the cursor returned is valid, get the phone number
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                String number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);

            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```